# semaphore array initialization in java

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, semaphore

I am trying to create a semaphore array in java and initialize all semaphores to 1. I tried the following: `private static Semaphore [] sem = new Semaphore [] {1,1,1,1,1};`

But i get the error Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Semaphore. How can i do this? I do not want to first declare and then initialize, it must be initialized when declared.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Side question: why that many semaphores? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am implementing the dining philosophers problem for 5 philosophers and i keep a semaphore for each of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are putting `int` values into a `Semaphore` array, hence the type mismatch. You need

```
private static Semaphore [] sem = new Semaphore [] {new Semaphore(1),
     new Semaphore(1), new Semaphore(1), new Semaphore(1), new Semaphore(1)};
```

Comment: @user1941394 than please don't forget to mark the answer as correct, as soon as SO allows you to (in about 10 minutes).

Answer (score 1):

I presume you would like to use `Semaphore(int permits)` constructor.

The only way to do that is as follows:

```
private static Semaphore [] sem = new Semaphore [] {
   new Semaphore(1),
   new Semaphore(1),
   new Semaphore(1),
   new Semaphore(1),
   new Semaphore(1)
};
```

Or using `for` loop (this approach will work perfectly fine if your array of `Semaphore` instances is much longer).

```
private static Semaphore [] sem = new Semaphore [5];
static {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        sem[i] = new Semaphore(1);
    }   
}
```

Also `for` loop would work perfectly fine if you have long number of semaphore permits not in sequence (or you would load permits from a configuration file) e.g.

```
private static Semaphore [] sem;

static {
    int [] semaphorePermits = {1,2,3,1,2,2,2,2,4,5,2,1,2,3,4,5,3,2,12,1,2,23,3};
    sem = new Semaphore[semaphorePermits.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < semaphorePermits.length; i++) {
        sem[i] = new Semaphore(semaphorePermits[i]);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are all semaphores going to represent permits over the same resource? In that case, you don't need an array, just a single `Semaphore` object, with a permit count of 5 or whatever. If you, on the other hand, have multiple resources, you can always add the semaphores to your array using a `for` loop.